# Git P4 rebase fails with 3 way merge issue

Tags: git, rebase, git-p4

We have recently migrated from p4 to git using git-p4

We have run

```
git-p4 clone //test/path1/...@all
#and incrementally started doing imports using 

git p4 rebase //test/path1/...@all
```

It has been working fine but off late few engineers started adding and deleting a file say test.sh in both p4 and git repo, and after that, git-p4 rebase started failing.

---

First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: first commit
Applying: Create jenkins-git-build.sh
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...

```
<stdin>:140: trailing whitespace.
##                                                                      ##  
<stdin>:165: trailing whitespace.
##                                                                      ##  
<stdin>:254: trailing whitespace.
##                                                                      ##  
<stdin>:328: trailing whitespace.
##                                                                      ##  
<stdin>:351: trailing whitespace.
##                                                                      ##  
warning: squelched 2 whitespace errors
warning: 7 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging components/tools/bin/jenkins-git-build.sh
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in components/tools/bin/jenkins-git-build.sh
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 Create jenkins-git-build.sh
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /gitdata/path1/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3297, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3291, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3074, in run
    return self.rebase()
  File "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3091, in rebase
    system("git rebase %s" % upstream)
  File "/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 198, in system
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git rebase remotes/p4/master' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I have resolved the conflict and tried skip option, but it still keeps complaining about each delta commit ..

```
warning: squelched 2 whitespace errors
warning: 7 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging components/tools/bin/jenkins-git-build.sh
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in components/tools/bin/jenkins-git-build.sh
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0006 Create jenkins-git-build.sh
```

If I keep skipping for 150 times+ then it says its complete.

But I want to fix the merge issue for ever and continue my incremental rebases smooth. Any help ?

I have tried resolving the conflicts and committing the changes as suggested [git p4 rebase attempts to reapply past commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106900/git-p4-rebase-attempts-to-reapply-past-commits) but that did not help.

Comment: An *add/add* conflict in Git occurs when the file is *not* present in the merge base, but is present in *both* the `HEAD` commit and the other commit you're merging. If the two copies of the file differ, Git does not know *which* copy to take (if any). To solve this merge conflict, pick the correct copy, or manually combine the two copies into the correct result, and `git add` that file, then use `git rebase --continue` to move on to the next commit. The merge base of the next commit will have that file (because the merge base of the *next* commit to be copied is the commit just copied).

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but git rebase --continue keeps complaining about the same file at different positions. Is there any way to permanently fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same file at different positions". Your rebase output, though, shows that you're using a non-interactive non-merge-flag `git rebase` (i.e., you're not running `git rebase -m` nor `git rebase -s <strategy>` nor `git rebase -i`). Such rebases don't detect renamed files; if someone has been re-arranging your file tree, you probably want one of the rebase variants that *does* detect renamed files.

Comment: Since your rebase is run by `git p4` you might need some special P4 flag, or to improve the `git-p4` command somehow, to achieve this. I have never used `git p4` so cannot do more than guess, here.

Comment: Thanks once again. 
This is what I see in the rebase-apply dir of git. And rebase complains about each of these patches everytime I run git p4 rebase.

```
0004  0014  ...  0246  0256    
```

I am just wondering, if there is any way to accept the changes from perforce for each rebase and continue.

Comment: I have tried the below command as per the above suggestion.
```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs refs/remotes/
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
[detached HEAD a68ea66] first commit
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in components/tools/bin/jenkins-git-build.sh

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

```

Comment: High level (add/add, modify/delete, etc) conflicts cam still occur regardless of `-X` options, but ideally this should only happen once now. It really depends on what you're rebasing though.